# Recording output audio with Swift

Tags: ios, audio, swift

Is it possible to record *output* audio in an app using Swift? So, for example, say I'm listening to a podcast, and I want to, within a separate app, record a small segment of the podcast's audio. Is there any way to do that?

I've looked around but have only been able to find information on recording microphone recording and such.

Comment: No. You can't. For reasons that should be obvious to do with privacy and rights management.

Comment: @marko When talking, it's good to have _some_ idea what one is talking about.

Comment: The OP seems to want to intercept the output audio of *another application* in iOS in order to record it. Further, there is the implication that the source material isn't otherwise available, as you'd clearly obtain it that way, were that the case.
This question is asked fairy frequently, and the answer doesn't change, nor is it likely to.  Were it to be possible, it would allow apps to maliciously record of audio from phone (or VOIP) calls, and allow the digital audio of paid-for content to be used in a way that wasn't intended by the publisher.

Comment: @marko And that is why my answer, to which your commented retort adds nothing constructive, explains what I believe _is_ possible. I draw the sharp distinction between tapping one's own audio and hijacking arbitrary sound output, the latter being impossible. But its impossibility has nothing to do with "privacy and rights management"; it has to do with the fact that there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you are producing the audio. If the production of the audio is within your control, you can put a *tap* on the output and record to a file as it plays. The easiest way is with the new AVAudioEngine feature (there are other ways, but AVAudioEngine is basically an easy front end for them).

Of course, if the real problem is to take a copy of a podcast, then obviously all you have to do is *download* the podcast as opposed to *listening* to it. Similarly, you could buffer and save streaming audio to a file. There are many apps that do this. But this is not because the device's output is being hijacked; it is, again, because we have control of the sound data *itself*.

Comment: Okay, so it seems like I would have two choices if I wanted to capture an audio segment of an "outside" podcast (one that I don't already have a full copy of): 1) buffer it from the source and record at a certain point; or 2) download it completely -- at which point I'd have access to the sound data, as you said -- and then, since I controlled the data, I could record a segment of it. Sound about right?

Comment: (1) sounds right, since this must be what apps that record radio streams are actually doing. As for (2), if you downloaded it completely you wouldn't _need_ to record a segment of it; the download _is_ a recording.

Comment: Presumably the apps that record a stream are using Audio Queue Services or some similar bit of Core Audio.

Comment: Ah, right... in (2), I assume I could somehow extract clips from the full download.

Comment: Certainly, just as it is easy to extract clips from any audio or video file.

Comment: @matt, I am successfully using an audio engine to do a real time pitch change, but I am unable to save the results. After reading your comment, tapping seems to be the way to go, but I am only finding resources to tap the mic. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am essentially trying to find the same answer requested in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012139/save-audio-file-with-changed-time-pitch-using-avaudioengine-in-swift

Comment: @user4812000 Do you found any solution? I'm not capable of tap the output audio. Maybe you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll have to write a kernel extension to do that

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html

You'd have to make your own audio driver to record it

It appears as though

That is how softonic made soundflowerbed.

http://features.en.softonic.com/how-to-record-internal-sound-on-a-mac

Comment: 1st: Soundflower/SoundflowerBed has nothing to do with Softonic, they just redistribute it. It's was created by Matt Ingalls.

Comment: 2nd: SoundflowerBed is just an audio redirector, Soundflower is the kernel extensions.