# Save audio file with changed time pitch using AVAudioEngine in Swift

Tags: swift, avaudioengine

Currently, I am trying to change the time pitch of an existing audio file from the Document folder, then override the old file with the modified one using AVAudioEngine. I have got the first part working using AVAudioPlayerNode and AVAudioUnitTimePitch. I have no idea about the second part though. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to your question?

Comment: I'm looking for that answer, too!! Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Comment: still looking for an answer ?